# How to restore a window while it is minimized in system tray?

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf form which has one main window. when i click a button in main window it i will show a  child window. I tried to restore the child window  but couldn't. how to restore while it is minimized in system tray?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
 if (this.MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
 {
     this.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
 }

 //bring window to front of all windows
 this.MainWindow.Activate();
```

this.MainWindow should be the reference to the window you want to maximize or bring to normal state.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've seen your code and It was correct for main window. But I want to restore a child window. when i click a button in main window it i will show a child window. I tried to restore the child window but couldn't. Plz give a suggestion for my child window. Thank you @sexta13